# Monomial polynomial has 0 as roots

Tags: polynomials

I was going through a solution of a particular problem, there it was written that monomial polynomial (polynomials having only one term) have $0$ as roots, in fact if it has real roots, all of them would be $0$. There was no more information given on this and I'm thinking how to orove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A monomial (in one variable) is of the form $p(x) = c x^k$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $c$ is a constant.  If $k \ge 1$, then $p(0) = 0$; if $k = 0$ and $c \ne 0$, there are no roots.

Comment: Hello. I learnt that a polynomial of degree k must have k roots as well. Is it possible for all those k roots to be equal?

Comment: @轻型八神 Yes. Consider the equation $x^2 = 0.$